# Multiple group in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table, named "table_log".

Here is the structure

```
---------------------------------------
|id_log | user_id | login_date         |
---------------------------------------
|1      | 1       |2014-09-02 14:58:53 |
|2      | 1       |2014-09-03 24:18:53 |
|3      | 1       |2014-09-02 14:58:53 |
|4      | 1       |2014-09-01 02:28:53 |
|5      | 2       |2014-09-04 01:48:53 |
|6      | 3       |2014-09-05 04:58:53 |
|7      | 2       |2014-09-06 03:58:53 |
----------------------------------------
```

I want to count number of user each days. not how much log is.

As an example data, I want to show it like this:

```
---------------------------
|date        | user_number|  
---------------------------
|2014-09-02  | 1          |
|2014-09-03  | 1          |
|2014-09-04  | 5          |
---------------------------
```

Does any can help me? How to query my database?

Comment: user_number means what?

Comment: Can you please try to explain this one: 'not how much log is.' once more...

Comment: Your desired data doesn`t match the input.Why user_number 4 on 2014-09-03?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date(login_date) AS date, count(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
  FROM table_log
 GROUP BY date(login_date)
```

The `date` function gives just the date-part of a `datetime` column, then it's a simple `group by`.

Comment: OP wants to count the number of users, I would suggest a `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`, as the number of logs doesn't matter.

Comment: @FrankySo: Show's 1 where? For what input!?

Comment: @JanickBernet : i'm so sorry. my fault. :D its working now. thankyou so much!

Comment: Franky So and @Janick How the output will come for 2014-09-04 fro 5 users in your query aspect? And, why down vote for me?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv: I think the example numbers are wrong. The question is rather unclear, but the number of distinct user visits is generally the value that's desired.

Comment: @punithasubramaniv I'm not the downvoter, but I assume that's because you count the dates and not the users.

Comment: @X.L.Ant okay ant. Actually the counts not proper in requirement screenshot. Thats why i mentioned in my post that the requirement issue and asked whther tht the o/p they expected!

Comment: @punithasubramaniv You asked, I try to provide an answer. Again, I didn't downvote. Anyway, downvotes happen sometimes, even on the best answers possible. Get over with.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your ques, but u expect it?

2014-09-03 there is one record how user number will come 4 ? which scenario u asking?

```
SELECT date(login_date) AS date, count(date(login_date))
FROM tbl
GROUP BY date(login_date)
```